# What do we actually mean by carrier lifetime in perovskite materials and where do charge carrier reside during that time?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, photon-emission, half-life

During time-resolved photoluminescence studies in perovskite materials, one sometimes says that it has a microsecond carrier lifetime. What do we actually mean by that? Where does the excited electron reside: in the conduction band (CB) or trap states inside the bandgap?
If it is CB minimum, it should instantly decay down to the valence band maximum and recombine. If we consider the above bandgap states, then relaxation processes take place on the ps to ns scale, not microseconds.
We also say that single crystals have a higher carrier lifetime than polycrystalline films. What is the carrier behaviour in those samples that gives rise to longer lifetimes?
Any reference or clarification is appreciated.

Comment: Decay is not instant by any means. Carriers in, say, GaAs have finite lifetimes. Shorter than silicon, sure…

Comment: *If it is CB minimum, it should instantly decay down to the valence band maximum and recombine.* This is not true, the carrier lifetime is what quantifies how long it takes for recombination to occur, on average. Polycrystalline and amorphous materials have defects which manifest as intra-gap states, providing additional recombination pathways and reducing carrier lifetimes.